# Best way to load multiple data in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to **Ruby On Rails**,
I'm working on an application which contains multiple model related to each other like:

1. `Restaurant`
2. `Branch`
3. `Favourite`
4. `Reviews`
5. `User`

These are related to each other like:

**Restaurant** `has_many branches`

**Branch** `belongs_to restaurant`,  `has_many favourites`, `has_many reviews`

**User** `has_many favourites`, `has_many reviews`

I'm writing an API where I will pass a `keyword` and `user Id` from params and should return related ***branches*** having the address like that `keyword` with **restaurant**, **favorites counts**, **reviews count**, and **is_fav (true/false) for use_id** keys within **branch hash**.

Now I'm trying to find the best way to get data within the **minimum time** from the database **without loop each and every branch and get restaurant, favorites, reviews every separate query**.

Is there any way to make fast API performance?

Comment: As I understand you want to write well-performance SQL-database query.
I could help you but you should provide table definitions of your models first. I can advise you right now about one thing - [counter caches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You should add to Branch model a two counter caches: reviews_count, favorites_count. If I understand your needs correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.

```
Branch.includes(:restaurants, :favourites, :reviews).where("restaurants.location like %?%", #{keyword})
```

Probably more conditions to this sample query you can add and get all data. FYI, this would apply a single join query to the database.